# Rodando script de criação de banco com constraints

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, query, querybuilder

Boa noite pessoas, eu criei um esquema de tabelas mas não sei como devo rodar o script nesse caso, pois tenho em cada tabela constraints que necessitam da criação das outras, tem algum método de adicionar a constraint depois da criação ou algum outro método para deixar o esquema de tabelas correto igual no script?

Estou usando o PostgreSQL como base de dados.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS store (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    nome VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    document VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    store_product INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (store_product) REFERENCES product (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    nome VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    price NUMERIC(15,2) NOT NULL,
    store_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    inventory_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (store_id) REFERENCES store (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (inventory_id) REFERENCES inventory (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS inventory (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    amount INTEGER NOT NULL,
    product_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product (id)
);
```

Comment: Não entendi o modelo confesso , nem vou analisar , mas no caso seria criar as tabelas e suas PKs e depois por "ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT" criar as FKs. https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/07/postgresql-how-to-add-constraint-to-existing-table.html

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: O problema é claro.

Comment: não vai conseguir assim, precisa criar todas as tabelas primeiro, e depois adicionar as constraints, mas tem um problema no seu modelo, referencias circular, pois store depende de produto e produto depende de store, isso é uma falha de modelagem que vai te dar problema na hora de inserir dados

Comment: Nossa Ricardo, foi um ótimo ponto, consegui rodar os scripts mas vou prestar mais atenção na modelagem, primeira vez, sugere alguma mudança?

Comment: Uma possível solução para esse erro seria criar uma tabela de relação entre ```store``` e ```produto```? @RicardoPontual

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O resultado que eu usei para o problema mencionado, foi uma remodelagem no meu esquema de banco de dados, usando chaves primárias compostas e uma tabela de relação, a tabela `inventory`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS store (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    nome VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    document VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    nome VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    price NUMERIC(15,2) NOT NULL,
    store_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, store_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS inventory (
    id SERIAL,
    product_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    store_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    amount INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id, store_id) REFERENCES product (id, store_id)
);
```

Assim sendo possível a relação que eu queria, e inserção de dados!

Comment: isso ajuda a criar o modelo mas não vai conseguir fazer insert nas tabelas de produto nem store, como as colunas são not null vai precisar passar um valor, e esse valor deve existir na outra tabela, ou seja, essa modelagem não é viável!
ou faz como colocou no comentário, criar uma tabela ProdutoStore ou precisa que os campos foreign key sejam null, o que é outro problema

Comment: Ajudaram demais pessoas, resolvi o esquema de um jeito diferente com as sugestões de vocês.

Comment: Alterei o comentário da resposta, se quiserem ver!!